# Android: How can items in dynamically-created listview open another self-owned activity by reusing the intent

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Now I am trying to write a discussion forum like application. I have already created a page that allows users to add new topics, with inputted topic name and content. And the topic will be added to a listView which is used to display a list of the new posts. So when I click to a specific item on the listView, it opens another activity that displays the content of the post. I am currently using Bundle and Intent to pass data and direct to the other activity, but the activity directed is always with the same data. So my question is, how can each item click direct to its own activity by reusing the same design of a xml file?

This is what I am trying to do on the item click:

```
private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.topicList);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent contentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContentPage.class);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("topicName", getTopic);
            bundle.putString("content", getContent);
            bundle.putString("dateTime", currentDateTimeString);
            contentIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(contentIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because on click on each item you need to get info of the selected item (which you are not doing) then add it to `Bundle`.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //postItem(s) is Object where your list is populated with
            postItem= (PostItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent contentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContentPage.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("topicName", postItem.getTopic());
            bundle.putString("content", postItem.getContent());
            bundle.putString("dateTime", postItem.currentDateTimeString());
            contentIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(contentIntent);
        }
    });
```